# mongodump with query on slave db

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I'm trying to dump from my secondary so I don't hurt the live traffic.

I can dump from it successfully. but if I add a query I get 0 documents.

What do I need to add to query succesfully to my slave?

```
0 Documents:
mongodump --host xxxx --port 27017 --username xxx --password xxx --db test --collection xxxx --query "{date_visited:{'$gte':new Date(1451606400000)}}" --out /dumps/xxxx-after-2016-01-01.json

All Documents:
mongodump --host xxxx --port 27017 --username xxx --password xxx --db test --collection xxxx --out /dumps/xxxx.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like that, i.e. swap the usages of double and single quotes to avoid any evaluation by the shell as noted in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--query)

> --query , -q
>
> Provides a JSON document as a query that optionally limits the documents included in the output of mongodump.
>
> You must enclose the query in single quotes (e.g. ') to ensure that it
>   does not interact with your shell environment.

---

```
mongodump --host xxxx --port 27017 --username xxx --password xxx --db test --collection xxxx --query '{date_visited:{"$gte":new Date(1451606400000)}}' --out /dumps/xxxx-after-2016-01-01.json
```

Comment: Glad to hear that